# How to access to system public directory

Tags: java, directory

I need help in finding a public directory of operating system where I can save a .txt file with informations.

I explain better: I have to save somewhere a txt file where I have saved some important informations but I'll have to give my program to different people from all over the world and I can't use directory that have name like "Users" because it will be translated in the language of the operating system.

So I'm looking for a directory that has the same name in all the language or better a method of an object that can let me access a public directory of the OS that can't be renamed and can be found in all OS.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I good bet is `System.getProperty("user.home")`. From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29):

> `user.home`   User's home directory

This is supposed to be cross-platform and I would expect it to work regardless of the OS language/locale (the JVM should get it from the system it's running on).

I would recommend against placing files in the home directory itself; a better practice is to create a sub-directory and store your files there.

Comment: I would further recommend putting the `data.txt` into a **sub-directory** of `user.home` based on the package name of the main class.  e.g. `com.our.Main` saves data to `${user.home}/com/our/data.txt`.  This helps avoid clashes with other apps. that want to save a `data.txt` that overwrites your own apps. version.  ;)